# Armbian enable UART2 for TX/RX

Tags: serial-port, armbian, uart

I'm trying to use the `UART1` and `UART2` of my device (a NanoPi NEO) to read serial data.

So far, `UART1` i fully functionnal and I can read and transmit data through `/dev/ttyS1`.

I've enabled `UART2` using the `armbian-config` hardware menu and it seems to have added the line in the `armbianEnv.txt`:

```
# cat /boot/armbianEnv.txt 
verbosity=1
bootlogo=false
console=serial
disp_mode=1920x1080p60
overlay_prefix=sun8i-h3
overlays=uart1 uart2 uart3
rootdev=UUID=f8644502-8a67-43df-8275-2953e5ef9c87
rootfstype=ext4
usbstoragequirks=0x2537:0x1066:u,0x2537:0x1068:u
```

The config does not seem to be the same for the two UARTs:

```
# cat /proc/tty/driver/serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28000 irq:137 tx:19080 rx:134 RTS|DTR
1: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28400 irq:138 tx:0 rx:4312 RTS|CTS|DTR
2: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28800 irq:139 tx:0 rx:0 CTS
3: uart:U6_16550A mmio:0x01C28C00 irq:140 tx:0 rx:0 RTS|CTS|DTR
4: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
5: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
6: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
7: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
```

Did I make something wrong or forget to run a command to enable `UART2` through `/dev/ttyS2` ?

I've also tried to add the following line to `armbianEnv.txt` but didn't help: `param_uart2_rtscts=1`